# Raspberry Pi 4にUbuntu Server 19.10をインストールした際のデフォルトユーザー名を変更する

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi 4にUbuntu Server 19.10をインストールした際のデフォルトのユーザー名を変更したいのですがどうすればよいのでしょうか?

デフォルトではユーザー名が`ubuntu`、パスワードも`ubuntu`になっており、これを例えば(ユーザー名:helloman パスワード:0123456789)というようなものに変更したいのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか?

どうやらSDカードにraspi用のimageを焼いた後、`user-data`というファイルを編集すればよいらしく、下記の例を参考にやってみたのですがうまくいきません。なぜでしょうか?

https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/examples.html

パスワードは数字だけのものに変更したいです。(弱いパスワードなのは承知していますがやってみたいです)

自分で編集したuser-data:

```yaml
#cloud-config

# This is the user-data configuration file for cloud-init. By default this sets
# up an initial user called "ubuntu" with password "ubuntu", which must be
# changed at first login. However, many additional actions can be initiated on
# first boot from this file. The cloud-init documentation has more details:
#
# https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/
#
# Some additional examples are provided in comments below the default
# configuration.

# Enable password authentication with the SSH daemon
ssh_pwauth: true
#### this section created by KiYugadgeter
#
#
system_info:
    default_user:
        name: helloman
        plain_text_passwd: '0123456789'
        home: /home/helloman
        shell: /bin/bash
        lock_passwd: true
        gecos: helloman
        grops: [adm, audio, cdrom, dialout, floppy, video, plugdev, netdev]

#
#
#
######## end of section
# On first boot, set the (default) ubuntu user's password to "ubuntu" and
# expire user passwords
chpasswd:
  expire: false
  list:
  - helloman:'0123456789'

## Add users and groups to the system, and import keys with the ssh-import-id
## utility
#groups:
#- robot: [robot]
#- robotics: [robot]
#- pi
#
users:
- default
#- name: robot
#  gecos: Mr. Robot
#  primary_group: robot
#  groups: users
#  ssh_import_id: foobar
#  lock_passwd: false
#  passwd: $5$hkui88$nvZgIle31cNpryjRfO9uArF7DYiBcWEnjqq7L1AQNN3

## Update apt database and upgrade packages on first boot
#package_update: true
#package_upgrade: true

## Install additional packages on first boot
#packages:
#- pwgen
#- pastebinit
#- [libpython2.7, 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1]

## Write arbitrary files to the file-system (including binaries!)
#write_files:
#- path: /etc/default/keyboard
#  content: |
#    # KEYBOARD configuration file
#    # Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.
#    XKBMODEL="pc105"
#    XKBLAYOUT="gb"
#    XKBVARIANT=""
#    XKBOPTIONS="ctrl: nocaps"
#  permissions: '0644'
#  owner: root:root
#- encoding: gzip
#  path: /usr/bin/hello
#  content: !!binary |
#    H4sIAIDb/U8C/1NW1E/KzNMvzuBKTc7IV8hIzcnJVyjPL8pJ4QIA6N+MVxsAAAA=
#  owner: root:root
#  permissions: '0755'

## Run arbitrary commands at rc.local like time
#runcmd:
#- [ ls, -l, / ]
#- [ sh, -xc, "echo $(date) ': hello world!'" ]
#- [ wget, "http://ubuntu.com", -O, /run/mydir/index.html ]
```

Comment: 念の為確認しますが、`grops: [adm, audio, ...` の `grops` は `groups` のはずで、これは質問欄に書き写す際の間違いでしょうか？

Comment: 拡張子なしの "user-data" を用意していた場合、代わりにファイル名を "user-data.txt" を試してみてください。

Comment: `grops`となっていたのは間違いでしたがそこを修正してもうまくいきませんでした。

Comment: ＠cubick 一度、raspi上でcloudinitが走った後にsdカードを抜いて、別のマシンでimage内のファイルを編集して、再度raspiに挿して起動させた時にはcloudinitが走るのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

user-data だと変更できないです。user-data が処理される前に /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg に書かれた内容で 作成されています。

いったん 別の Linux 環境で MicroSD の ext4 パーティションをマウントして、etc/cloud/cloud.cfg をエディタで編集してユーザー名を変更してください。 そのあとで、user-data でパスワード設定するようにしてみてください。

もしくは、普通にインストールして、userdel ubuntu してから useradd helloman してみても良いかもしれません。

1. ubuntu ユーザでログイン
2. sudo -s
3. passwd で root のパスワードを設定
4. ログアウト → root でログイン
5. userdel ubuntu
6. useradd helloman
7. passwd helloman
8. passwd -l root